# Can you create a plane from vuforia target images?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

As seen in the photo below i have 4 vuforia target images. What i want to achieve is to measure the angle of the red axis joining two target images, against a plane which i want to generate using the three target images connected by the green line. Hopefully this is more understandable. How would i go about generating that plane with those three target images?

[![][1]][1]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your idea or add a sketch? Im really not sure at all what you want to do with three vuforia target images.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is extremely broad! However I'll give it a shot:

I'm assuming by "Plane" you mean an actually visible 3D mesh. Otherwise you could directly use the 3 given coordinates to create a mathematical [`Plane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane-ctor.html).

First of all for a plane you usually use a rectangular mesh .. it is unclear in your question how exactly you want to built that from the 3 coordinates you get.

I'm simply assuming here you create a [Parallelogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram) directly using the 3 coordinates for the corners `A`, `B` and`C` and then adding a 4th one `D` by adding the vector `B`→`C` to `A`

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class PlaneController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target1;
    public Transform target2;
    public Transform target3;

    private MeshFilter meshFilter;
    private Mesh mesh;
    private Vector3[] vertices;

    private void Awake()
    {
        meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        mesh = meshFilter.mesh;

        vertices = new Vector3[4];

        // Set the 4 triangles (front and backside)
        // using the 4 vertices
        var triangles = new int[3 * 4];

        // triangle 1 - ABC
        triangles[0] = 0;
        triangles[1] = 1;
        triangles[2] = 2;
        // triangle 2 - ACD
        triangles[3] = 0;
        triangles[4] = 2;
        triangles[5] = 3;

        // triangle 3 - BAC
        triangles[6] = 1;
        triangles[7] = 0;
        triangles[8] = 2;
        // triangle 4 - ADC
        triangles[9] = 0;
        triangles[10] = 3;
        triangles[11] = 2;

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // build triangles according to target positions
        vertices[0] = target1.position - transform.position; // A
        vertices[1] = target2.position - transform.position; // B
        vertices[2] = target3.position - transform.position; // C

        // D = A  + B->C
        vertices[3] = vertices[0] + (vertices[2] - vertices[1]);

        // update the mesh vertex positions
        mesh.vertices = vertices;

        // Has to be done in order to update the bounding box culling
        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

After you changed the question: In this case you don't really need the visual plane but as mentioned before create the purely mathematical construct [`Plane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane-ctor.html).

The planes normal is a vector standing always 90° to the plane. You then can use e.g. [`Vector3.Angle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html) in order to get the angular difference between the [`normal`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane-normal.html) and your red vector (lets say between `target1` and `target4`). Something like

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
using UnityEngine;

public class AngleChecker : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Input")]

    public Transform target1;
    public Transform target2;
    public Transform target3;
    public Transform target4;

    [Header("Output")]
    public float AngleOnPlane;

    private void Update()
    {
        AngleOnPlane = GetAngle();
    }

    private float GetAngle()
    {
        // get the plane (green line/area)
        var plane = new Plane(target1.position, target2.position, target3.position);

        // get the red vector
        var vector = target4.position - target1.position;

        // get difference
        var angle = Vector3.Angle(plane.normal, vector);

        // since the normal itself stands 90° on the plane
        return 90 - angle;
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    // ONLY FOR VISUALIZATION
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        // draw the plane
        var mesh = new Mesh
        {
            vertices = new[]
            {
                target1.position,
                target2.position,
                target3.position,
                target3.position + (target1.position - target2.position)
            },
            triangles = new[] {
                0, 1, 2,
                0, 2, 3,
                1, 0, 2,
                0, 3, 2
            }
        };
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        Gizmos.color = Color.white;
        Gizmos.DrawMesh(mesh);

        // draw the normal at target1
        var plane = new Plane(target1.position, target2.position, target3.position);
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
        Gizmos.DrawRay(target1.position, plane.normal);

        Handles.Label(target1.position + plane.normal, "plane normal");

        // draw the red vector
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(target1.position, target4.position);

        Handles.Label(target4.position , $"Angle to plane: {90 - Vector3.Angle(plane.normal, target4.position - target1.position)}");
    }
#endif
}
```

[image]

---

After your comment I see you **want** to make it also visible in the scene.
So we are back to also the first part of my answer where exactly this was done.

Simply add the visible plane to the scene as well by merging both before mentioned scripts.

For making the text visual I recommend to go through the [Unity UI Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIToolkits.html).

For making the line appear there are two options. You can either use a [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) ([API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html)) or simply use a cube your rotate and scale accordingly:

```
// ! UNCOMMENT THIS IF YOU RATHER WANT TO USE THE LINERENDERER !
//#define USE_LINERENDERER

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class PlaneController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Input")]

    // Reference these in the Inspector
    public Transform target1;
    public Transform target2;
    public Transform target3;
    public Transform target4;

    [Space]

    public MeshFilter meshFilter;

    [Header("Output")]
    public float AngleOnPlane;

    public Text angleText;
    public float lineWith = 0.05f;

#if USE_LINERENDERER
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
#else
    public MeshRenderer cubeLine;
#endif

    private Mesh mesh;
    private Vector3[] vertices;
    private Vector3 redLineDirection;

    // if using line renderer
    private Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[2];

    private void Start()
    {
        InitializePlaneMesh();

#if USE_LINERENDERER
        InitializeLineRenderer();
#endif
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        // update the plane mesh
        UpdatePlaneMesh();

        // update the angle value
        UpdateAngle();
#if USE_LINERENDERER
        // update the line either using the line renderer
        UpdateLineUsingLineRenderer();
#else
        // update the line rather using a simple scaled cube instead
        UpdateLineUsingCube();
#endif
    }

    private void InitializePlaneMesh()
    {
        if (!meshFilter) meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();

        mesh = meshFilter.mesh;

        vertices = new Vector3[4];

        // Set the 4 triangles (front and backside)
        // using the 4 vertices
        var triangles = new int[3 * 4];

        // triangle 1 - ABC
        triangles[0] = 0;
        triangles[1] = 1;
        triangles[2] = 2;
        // triangle 2 - ACD
        triangles[3] = 0;
        triangles[4] = 2;
        triangles[5] = 3;

        // triangle 3 - BAC
        triangles[6] = 1;
        triangles[7] = 0;
        triangles[8] = 2;
        // triangle 4 - ADC
        triangles[9] = 0;
        triangles[10] = 3;
        triangles[11] = 2;

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
    }

#if USE_LINERENDERER
    private void InitializeLineRenderer()
    {
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;
        lineRenderer.startWidth = lineWith;
        lineRenderer.endWidth = lineWith;
        lineRenderer.loop = false;
        lineRenderer.alignment = LineAlignment.View;
        lineRenderer.useWorldSpace = true;
    }
#endif

    private void UpdatePlaneMesh()
    {
        // build triangles according to target positions
        vertices[0] = target1.position - transform.position; // A
        vertices[1] = target2.position - transform.position; // B
        vertices[2] = target3.position - transform.position; // C

        // D = A  + B->C
        vertices[3] = vertices[0] + (vertices[2] - vertices[1]);

        // update the mesh vertex positions
        mesh.vertices = vertices;

        // Has to be done in order to update the bounding box culling
        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
    }

    private void UpdateAngle()
    {
        // get the plane (green line/area)
        var plane = new Plane(target1.position, target2.position, target3.position);

        // get the red vector
        redLineDirection = target4.position - target1.position;

        // get difference
        var angle = Vector3.Angle(plane.normal, redLineDirection);

        // since the normal itself stands 90° on the plane
        AngleOnPlane = Mathf.Abs(90 - angle);

        // write the angle value to a UI Text element
        angleText.text = $"Impact Angle = {AngleOnPlane:F1}°";

        // move text to center of red line and a bit above it
        angleText.transform.position = (target1.position + target4.position) / 2f + Vector3.up * 0.1f;

        // make text always face the user (Billboard)
        // using Camera.main here is not efficient! Just for the demo
        angleText.transform.forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
    }

#if USE_LINERENDERER
    private void UpdateLineUsingLineRenderer()
    {
        positions[0] = target1.position;
        positions[1] = target4.position;

        lineRenderer.SetPositions(positions);
    }
#else
    private void UpdateLineUsingCube()
    {
        // simply rotate the cube so it is facing in the line direction
        cubeLine.transform.forward = redLineDirection.normalized;

        // scale it to match both target positions with its ends
        cubeLine.transform.localScale = new Vector3(lineWith, lineWith, redLineDirection.magnitude);

        // and move it to the center between both targets
        cubeLine.transform.position = (target1.position + target4.position) / 2f;
    }
#endif
}
```

Result using the LineRenderer

[image]

Result using the cube which looks almost the same

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your reply, sorry I am new to unity, vuforia and coding in general, I have edited my question. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Hey back there ;) Updated the answer. In that case you would only need a mathematical plane and use the angle difference between the planes `normal` and the red vector between lets say target4 and target1

Comment: How I implemented it ... it doesn't matter on which object you put this. I have simply created an empty gameObject and attached it to it. Important is only that you reference the 4 targets via the Inspector. If you need the angle on in a specific moment I would ofcourse make the `GetAngle` method `public` and delete the `Update` method for not wasting resources. The `OnDrawGizmos` can be completely deleted .. was just used for the demo

Comment: You have been extremely helpful thank you very much, however do you know if this code can actually be applied to vuforia target images as when i try to implement it i get error messages displaying: The name 'Target'1 does not exist in the current context . For each target.

Comment: `in real life` what do you mean? ^^ If this is done in the `Update` method it is in "real time"

Comment: sorry i did not word that well. it is in real time yes, but i want to actually have the plane that is created, the normal line and the red axis visible in camera mode. When i press play in demo mode it does trace the target image and the plane and angles change in real time, but only in the game scene. I want it all to be visible when using a camera so i can build it into an app which i phone can use to measure angles. does this make sense?

Comment: Please help, the plane is visible in my scene. However, when I press play the camera detects the image targets however nothing is overlaid. The plane is not visible in the camera screen. How do i make the plane and the red line appear over the target images?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Please don't push us for answers .. we are helping out in our free time. Since your question currently gets broader and broader this was the last edit to my answer. If you have specific question about implementations please do some research or open a new question. E.g. how to make meshes and Text visible in the scene is actually already way out of scope of your question ..

Comment: derHugo, i am sorry for the way i have handled this question. Furthermore i did not know you could upvote answers as i am new to all of this, i apologise, thank you so much for your help I am very appreciative and in future i will be more responsible in the way i reply and handle questions

Comment: I have successfully implemented your code except for the text. I have created a text UI and assigned it to the script however the text does not position where it should above the line. The text therefore is not visible. Any suggestions on what i am doing wrong?